# Insert dbcc output into a temporary table in pdw (Parallel Datawarehouse)

Tags: sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I am trying to run the below code in PDW but am facing error:

```
Create table #t
(
    rspace int,
    dspace int,
    ispace int,
    uspace int, 
    pnode int
)
with (location = user_db)

insert into #t
    dbcc pdw_showspaceused
```

When I try to run this I am getting error

> parse error at line 1 column 16  : Incorrect syntax near 'dbcc'.

I have tried using dynamic querying to solve this but am not able to use a SQL Server variable to run dynamic querying..

Please help me as am stuck at this..